# Date Regular Expression Match 2 or 1 Digit Date or Month

Tags: regex

I Have this regex a perfect to to match mm/dd/yyyy on all condition time format but i need to modify it a little bit

if someone insert 09/04/1980 its work perfect, but this 5/9/1990 (1 digit) will error :(

can someone fix it for me ?

this is my current regex :

```
(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))/(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: Why, just why developers attempt to solve every problem in the world using regex

Comment: I'm just trying learn regex, but when it become this long it's so hard to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])-31))\/(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Try this.Made `0` optional.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/65

Comment: wow, i've been placing those here and there to no avail. how could it could be so easy. anyway nice website it is

Comment: @machun yes it is.Leaning regex is fun there.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T use regex for this. I'll provide pesudocode since you've not specified language. You just need to split on `\` and convert the array elements to numbers and then do simple `if` condition.

```
if(arr[0] < 0 && arr[0] > 32){
   // validated the month
}
```